# Components not getting saved in Sketchup

Tags: sketchup

I use Sketchup Pro version 19 and a problem I have is that my components are not saved between sessions.

In other words, if I define several components then they appear in the component list. But if I then close and open the model again the components are gone.

Do I need to explicitly save components?

-------------Update

I tried re-adding my component, and when I tried to add one with the same name, it gave an error and the components in the model suddenly appeared in the list. Maybe its just a bug, that you need to create a component before you see the existing components?

Answer (score 0):

Components can be saved outside the model you have open if you choose to, and this is how you build your own component library; however the act of simply creating a component doesn't do this - it saves it into the model file itself. You need to manually save that component out to a specific location to access it whilst in other SketchUp files.

Hope that helps.